# Display \n and \r in output

Tags: perl, file, output, directory

Sometimes when I am working in Perl with files I get a "No such file or directory," and it turns out to be because there is a newline or space in the name of the file. Is there a way to configure the output to display these?

Comment: What output? If your perl code doesn't handle spaces and newlines in filenames it's buggy. Perhaps you should post your code.

Comment: You can display whitespace with `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; print Dumper $yourvar`

Comment: Perl doesn't display anything at all on error, leaving the error handling up to you. If you want to display the path on error, that's entirely up to you. If you wish to show newlines as `\n`, what's stopping you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose values that may contain unexpected spaces or newlines etc with single-primes when displaying them. Something like:

```
print "The file name is '$filename'\n";
```

In the output the placements of single-primes clearly indicates whether `$filename` contains newlines, leading spaces or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 3):

From the perlmonks [Basic debugging checklist](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=745674),

Check for unexpected whitespace :: 
Check for unprintable characters by converting them into their ASCII hex codes using `ord`

```
my $copy = $str;
$copy =~ s/([^\x20-\x7E])/sprintf '\x{%02x}', ord $1/eg;
print ":$copy:\n";
```